# How is fflush(stdin) changing the output in below code?

Tags: c

q. After adding `fflush(stdin)` the `a[0]` of string a have an character but when I remove it I can add one less chracter th that same string the `a[0]` character is blank. i am not having this problem when using this for integer input array. i want to know the reason behind it not alternate option(like getchar)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[50], b;
    int c, d, e, f;
    printf("enter the size of the string");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter the string");
    for (d = 0; d < c; d++) 
    {
        scanf("%c",&a[d]);
    }
    for(d = 0; d < c; d++)
    {
        printf("%d %c\n",d,a[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin)`, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi that should be the answer....

Comment: use `getchar()` instead to consume the linefeed (and this has been answered before I believe)

Comment: I notice, that the duplicate is almost exactly the same question, in the future make sure that no one has asked this before, before asking.

Comment: A tip for your next question: When you write your title you will get a list of possibly related questions. If one of them have the *exact same title* as yours, then it might be a good idea to check it out first.

Comment: i am a beginner so a detailed answer would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: getchar instead os scanf is not changing the output @Jean-François Fabre